# WinForms - Will UserControl.Dispose dispose Image in PictureBox as well?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have user control with generated code in its Designer file:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {            
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

User control contains few PictureBoxes with images (loaded from disk and Resx file). Should I dispose these image by myself in Dispose method of usercontrol, or can I trust that "components.Dispose()" which is disposing PictureBox components will dispose as well images currently loaded in PictureBoxes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PictureBox will not automatically dispose the loaded images; what if you were also using the image somewhere else? Likewise, setting the `Image` property to some other image doesn't dispose the original image either.

To be sure, this is the code of `PictureBox`'s `Dispose` code:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (disposing)
    this.StopAnimate();
  base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

As you can see, it does not call `image.Dispose()` (and neither does `StopAnimate`). You would have to do this yourself (or let the garbage collector handle it for you). Make sure that the image is not being used anywhere else, though!